# Docker-compose service with --service-ports flag as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

**tl;dr: Is there a way to specify the --service-ports flag as a default in the compose file?**

With my rails applications I usually have a this `command:` in my web service:

`command: bash -c "rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rake db:seed && RAILS_ENV=development puma"`

So, with a docker-compose up, I'm all set but if I want to debug using pry, I have to stop my web service and run `docker-compose run --service-ports web puma`

For my development compose file I would like for the web service to be run with --service-ports flag as a default. Is there anyway to specify this on the compose file so that I get everything ready in a single command? (docker-compose up)